# List View Webpart not showing full toolbar

Tags: list, web-part

I have a list that have placed on a page as a web part that defaults to no toolbar.  Even when I change the toolbar type through the web part properties, it will not change.  I can change the toolbar to summary and show no problem.  This is important because I have a custom action associated with a workflow that needs to be accessible through the ribbon.

Am I missing something?

**Update**

When I create a wiki page and add a list view web part, I have the ability to show the full toolbar.

Comment: are u tried to change it to show tool bar instead of full tool bar ?

Comment: I have but the show tool bar doesn't give me access to the ribbon at the top of the page, everything is greyed out.  I am only able to get access to the ribbon by using summary toolbar but this doesn't show the custom action button I created.